# bootstrap modal in rails doesn't work properly (not even without turbolinks)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, turbolinks

I have a rails app using bootstrap modal with AJAX. I have 2 problems:

1. Even with putting //= require jquery.turbolinks (right after req jquery) and  the //= require turbolinks after //= require bootstarp-sprockets in the application.js, my js.erb files (new,update,delete) won't get executed when I click on the submit buttons of the modals.
2. Without turbolinks everything works fine (creating, updating, deleting), except one thing. If I create a new task it will displayed immediately after clicking on the modal's submit button thanks to AJAX, but if I click right away on the edit/delete (delete happens with modal as well) button of the freshly created object, the modal doesn't pop up. After page reload, everything works fine again.
   It's weird since if I edit a not new object with the modal then I can click again on the edit/delete and update/destroy the same object. New modal works fine as well, so if I create a new object I can click on the new button again and the modal shows up. So there is issue only with the creating a new one then edit that object combination.

Have sby encountered the same problems?

So my current application.js without turbolinks is the following at the moment:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chat
//= require refile
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require private_pub
//= require_tree .
```

create.js.erb:

```
var ready = function () {
    $("#newtask").modal('hide');
    $(".task_name_company").val('');
    $(".contentarea").val('');
    $(".task_deadline").val('');

    //different div class for different partials
    $(".newtaskinsert").prepend('<%= j render @task %>');
    $(".newtaskinsert2").prepend('<%= j render partial: "tasks/task_between", locals: { task: @task } %>');
    $("#task_<%= @task.id %>").hide().fadeIn(1000);

    //26= pagination(12)*every task has 2 tr(2)+ extra task that must be hidden(2)=12*2+2
    var n = $('tr').length;
    if (n > 26) {
        $("tr").slice((-2*(n-26)/2)-1).fadeOut(500);
    };
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

update.js.erb:

```
var ready = function () {
    $('#updatetask_<%= @task.id %>').modal('hide');

    $('#task_<%= @task.id %>').fadeOut(400, function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $(".newtaskinsert").prepend('<%= j render @task %>');
        $(".newtaskinsert2").prepend('<%= j render partial: "tasks/task_between", locals: { task: @task } %>');
    });
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i am having the same problems.